# uWSGI Emperor does not reload Vassal by touching the .ini file

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have multiple uWSGI vassals, all monitored by uwsgi emperor. I update the code for my app (Django) and I want the emperor to perform a clean reload of one of the vassals. To do that I

```
touch vassal-foo.ini
```

In the logs I see `[emperor] reload the uwsgi instance vassal-foo.ini`. This sounds promising, but the app is not reloaded. It continues to run the old version. Checking the process (PID) startup time, indeed, it has not been restarted.

Any hints what might cause this? Few things that might be uncommon:

- Neither the emperor nor the vassal run in master mode
- Emperor was installed with pip and runs under `initctl`
- `kill -9`-ing the vassal triggers a correct reload (obviously)
- I use symlinks
- I have a secondary thread inside my python app (`threading.Thread(target).start()`) running with `daemon=True`

Things I tried and did not work:

- Run the process without any additional threads (remove `threading.Thread(target).start()`)
- Touching with `touch --no-dereference vassal-foo.ini`
- Starting emperor with `--emperor-nofollow`

vassal-foo.ini:

```
master         = false
processes      = 1
thunder-lock   = true
enable-threads = true
socket         = /tmp/%n.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

Emperor:

```
exec /tmp/uwsgi --emperor /tmp/configs/uwsgi/ --die-on-term --uid me --gid me --logto /tmp/logs/uwsgi-emperor.log
```

uWSGI version

```
$ uwsgi --version
2.0.17
```

Comment: Maybe try with `touch --no-dereference <INI_FILE>`? This will change the timestamp of the actual file and not the symlink

Comment: Tried as well. Also tried modifying the file itself.

Comment: According to the docs, you may want to start the emperor using the `--emperor-nofollow` option. Text from docs: ``Finally, start the Emperor with the --emperor-nofollow option. Now you can reload each vassal separately with the command: touch --no-dereference $INI_FILE``

Comment: The `--emperor-nofollow` option did not help either.

Comment: Try and add this to your uwsgi config - `touch-reload = /path/to/file/vassal-foo.ini`. Then restart your uwsgi process and see if it works.

Comment: @xyres That did not work either

Comment: I am still looking for suggestions.

Comment: Running the vassal as maser works, but I would like to not have to run as master if possible, as that creates other problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your vassal not run in master mode.

All the ways uwsgi reload a requires master process.

In emperor mode, when you touch the ini, the emperor send a sighup to the vassal and record in the log that the vassal is reload. But if the vassal doesn't has a master it just ignore the sighup. So that is why you see reload in log but nothing happened.